# GCP Identity Aware Proxy for on-premises apps

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I have a question about GCP BeyondCorp Enterprise license and Identity Aware Proxy for on-premises apps.

Documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp-enterprise/docs/securing-on-premises

I thought that iap for on-premise needs interconnect or cloud VPN, but Documentation nothing talk about this.

Is it possible to configure iap for public IP on-premise app without interconect?

I see it that way :

- on-premise app has a public ip address
- on-premise app firewall allow traffic only from one IP (google load balancer associated with iap connector)
- all traffic incoming to google iap is forwarded to on-prem public ip with added appropriate iap headers.

Comment: Diagram for on-prem here shows interconnect : https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview and https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-iap-for-on-prem-apps-overview#how_cloud_iap_for_on_prem_works

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure iap for public IP on-premise app without
> interconnect?

No. Your on-premises network must be connected to a VPC. That requires Cloud Interconnect.

When a request is sent to an on-premises app, IAP authenticates and authorizes the user request. It then routes the request to the IAP connector. The IAP connector forwards the request through a site-to-site connection established with Cloud Interconnect from Google Cloud to the on-premises network.

There are additional requirements. This link provides more details.

[Overview of IAP for on-premises apps](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-iap-for-on-prem-apps-overview)

[image]